# per user lxc containers

Tags: users, user-profile, lxc

I am sure I saw how to do this on a webpage around the intergoogle somewhere. 
But Is it possible to have your system setup so when you create a user on your machine they log into their own LXC container?

Answer (score 0):

You could set this up by setting the user's shell to chroot into the LXC container using the tools provided by LXC.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but could you provide just a wee bit more details. Or an example would be even better

Comment: Please be more specific: lxc-attach, lxc-console, lxc-execute or something different?